# Visual Studio C++ code how to autoindent preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, visual-studio

**How to use autoindent the preprocessor directives**

> For example in Visual studio all preprocessor directives intended like
>   this

```
void test(){
#if _SOME_VAR
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
#if _SOME_VAR2
      std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
#endif
#endif
}
```

How can i make code auto indents like this

```
void test(){
  #if _SOME_VAR
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    #if _SOME_VAR2
      std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
    #endif
  #endif
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't, preprocessor directives should start at the first column.

Comment: VS is not capable of formatting code properly. Both built-in formatter and built-in clang-format are flawed.

Comment: @VTT You can always write your own if you are not happy...

Comment: @nonsensation Your answer is realy true. Just write as answer.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I wish I could. Given that after all these years hundreds of skilled professionals failed to create a tool capable of at least dealing with indentation I stand no chance.

Comment: Although I agree with VTT about both VS and clang-format, I think it is more because C++ has so many edge cases that the layout aesthetics are very difficult to automate with a reformatter.  Throw in the the C Preprocessor in the mix, and it exacerbates the automatic formatting greatly.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, why they should start at the first column, apart from the fact that it is an ancient requirement by preprocessors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is

> Tools->Options->Text Editor->Indentation->Position of preprocessor
>   directives

[image]